# inserting unwanted additional empty record in mysql db using Fetch js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post, fetch-api

I'm using the Fetch API in my **js** code to send a POST request to my API :

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
  return response.json();
}

let obj1 = {
  "title": "do something",
  "body": "theBody",
  "author": "Me",
  "cat_id": "2"
}

postData('http://localhost:1598/phprest/api/create.php', obj1)
```

But for some reason there an extra empty record added to the database and I don't know why.

[image]

Here is my **PHP API** code :

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With');

include_once('../core/initialize.php');

$post = new Post($con);


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$post->title = $data->title;
$post->body = $data->body;
$post->author = $data->author;
$post->cat_id = $data->cat_id;


if ($post->create()) {
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'message' => 'Post created',
            'json_Request' => json_encode($post)
        )
    );
    // echo ();
} else {
    echo json_encode(
        array('message' => 'Post not created')
    );
    echo (json_encode($post));
}

?>
```

And the **PHP** code for the `create` function :

```
public function create()
    {
        $queryc = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . ' SET title = :title, body = :body, author = :author, cat_id = :cat_id ';

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($queryc);

        $this->title    = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->title));
        $this->body     = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->body));
        $this->author   = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->author));
        $this->cat_id   = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->cat_id));

        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $this->title);
        $stmt->bindParam(':body', $this->body);
        $stmt->bindParam(':author', $this->author);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cat_id', $this->cat_id);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        }
        printf("Error %s. \n", $stmt->error);

        return false;
    }
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: What happens in the constructor for `$post = new Post($con)`?

Comment: public function __construct($con)
    {
        $this->con = $con;
    }